# some ask of jquery.window(jquery source code)?

Tags: jquery

jquery source code

```
isWindow: function( obj ) {
        return obj != null && obj === obj.window;
    },
```

1.why？:obj!=null

2.why？:obj===obj.window;

not: obj===window;

Can this be?

```
isWindow:function(obj){
return obj===window;
}
```

can you give som test to say the method`obj==window`is can not receive correct answer

```
console.log($.isWindow(window))//true
console.log($.isWindow(null))//false
console.log($.isWindow(undefined))//false
above test is right
```

Comment: Considering the millions of web sites that have run jQuery and many years of cross browser bugs one can only guess as to why it was written this way and why they don't use your more simplified version

Comment: _“can not receive correct answer”_ — depends on what the correct answer _is_. `obj == window` throws an error if you’re not in an environment with a globally available `window`, as explained in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

1. The idea is that it then won't crash with `Cannot read property 'window' of null` for `isWindow(null)` but just return `false` (same for `undefined` as `undefined == null`).
2. Because what this code is trying to do is to detect that it is the global object by checking whether it contains itself. Since I can access a global variable `x` as `window.x` that implies that I can access the global variable `window` itself as `window.window` too (or `window.window.window`, etc.).

   Your suggestion would not work if run in an environment that doesn't have `window` as global object but something else (like node.js which has `global`), it would then crash with `window is not defined` instead of returning `false`. Also it would also return `true` if the argument is for example `true` and there happens to be a global variable `var window = true` existing as, even though `true` surely isn't a window object.

However this code is not perfect of course. Because it only checks this one property of the window object, so it is easily fooled. Depending on what exact purpose the function has, there would be better ways. But to know what better way would make sense, you'd first have to know how exactly the function is intended to be used (check whether the argument is just any window object? Or the global object? Does it have to run on platforms without window? In this case, should it check for the corresponding equivalent global object, or just always return `false`? Etc.).

Answer (score 0):

why`obj.window===window`not`obj===window`

because if you view have iframe,that iframe have it's window,so that have two window,one is global window,another is iframe's window,you cant not judge that is global(window) if you use`obj === window`,so you can use `obj.window===window`

why `obj.window===window` can judge?

you can see above answser

it use the thought of Duck model